# Iterating React component children

Tags: reactjs, children

Is there anyway or any entry point where I can find the actual input `(child.type === 'input')` in the children tree?

```js
class MyForm extends React.Component {
  parseChildren(children) {
    React.Children.forEach(children, child => {
      if (child) {
        console.log('type', child.type);
        if (child.props && child.props.children) {
          this.parseChildren.bind(this)(child.props.children);
        }
      }
    });
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.parseChildren(this.props.children);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.parseChildren(this.props.children);
  }
  render() {
    return <form>{this.props.children}</form>;
  }
}

class MyInput extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <p>
        My beautiful input <input {...this.props} />
      </p>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyForm>
    <MyInput type="text" />
  </MyForm>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Do you want to check if a child is an instance of `MyInput` class ?

Comment: No. I want to check if somewhere deep down in the rendered tree of the child there is a input component (the react wrapper arround the dom input not the dom node).

Answer (score 0):

The problem you described is not very much clear. What do you want to achieve?

It seems to me it is not the best way to pass children inside `MyForm` and then render only some of them.

Why not you filter your components (inputs) data before passing them as `Form's children` and then pass only those that match your search criteria? Or, maybe I understood you wrong?

Comment: My problem is related to input fields decoration after they are placed in a form.